# Threaded Code Is Causing the UI To Hang

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I wrote a simple class to generate arrays as I needed some hard-coded random arrays for my own debugging purposes, however despite calling the timely operations in a separate worker thread my UI still hangs! Here's the code...

```
    private static Random randGenerator = new Random();

    private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dataType = "System.";
        if (typeComboBox.Text != "Byte")
            dataType += signedCheckBox.Checked ? "" : "U";
        else if (typeComboBox.Text == "Byte")
            dataType += signedCheckBox.Checked ? "S" : "";
        dataType += typeComboBox.Text;

        generateButton.Enabled = false;

        new Thread(() =>
            {
                Process(Type.GetType(dataType), (int)sizeNumericUpDown.Value, hexCheckBox.Checked);
            }).Start();
    }

    private void Process(Type type, int size, bool hex)
    {
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sBuilder.Append(string.Format(@"{0}[] values = new {0}[{1}] {{", type.Name, size));

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int random = randGenerator.Next(0, GetIntegralMaxValue(type));
            sBuilder.Append((hex ? "0x" + random.ToString("x2") : random.ToString()) + (i < size - 1 ? ", " : " };"));
        }

        outputTextBox.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            outputTextBox.Text = sBuilder.ToString();
        });
    }

    private int GetIntegralMaxValue(Type type)
    {
        var field = type.GetField("MaxValue").GetValue(null);
        return Convert.ToInt32(field);
    }
```

I thought that maybe the issue lied with trying to access objects created on the main thread so instead I passed them to the method. I also tried declaring my randGenerator object within the class but still no luck. Could anybody identify the issue?

Comment: Is it hanging indefinitely? Is anything else running in the background and trying to access the UI thread?

Comment: No only until the operation is complete. And this is the only code in my class.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? If it's massive, it could just take a long time to update. One idea, though, you might call `sBuilder.ToString()` before invoking : `var s = sBuilder.ToString(); ... outputTextBox.Text = s;

Comment: On my computer, the hanging begins at 50,000 iterations and that's only for half a second. The more iterations and random numbers to be generated, the longer the operation takes obviously.

I tried your suggestion but no luck. I don't understand why the UI would hang as the GUI thread is completely free.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why do you need to precalc the random values? If you always want the same random numbers, why don't you simply use `new Random` with a specific (hardcoded) seed?

Comment: I haven't fully looked through the code, but the usual reason for UI 'hanging' when not explicitly blocking is flooding of the Windows message queue with the posted messages that are used to support BeginInvoke.  The GUI thread, loaded down with complex visual component updates, cannot keep up and the mouse/keyboard messages get lost in the crowd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextBox is not designed to hold a large set of data - it becomes very slow when amount of data increases. I would say that populating of the StringBuilder takes about 5% of time while assigning this data to TextBox (which executes in UI thread) takes remaining 95% of time. You can easily check this. Just run this code in debug mode and click "Pause" button during hanging. It should break on "outputTextBox.Text = sBuilder.ToString();" line.